# How to disable groups and sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

Windows 7 has some great features for sharing stuff with the other computers and other family members in your house.

But... for someone on a single computer and no other computers in the home, those features are just a lot of omni-present options that don't make any sense in that context.

Is there a way to opt out of all the sharing capability? Not just not use it, but actually get those options not to appear everywhere (for example, when you right click any file)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to the Homegroup function. [Here](http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7customization/disable-homegroup-windows-7/) is a guide how to disable it.